# LKFS or LUFS maximum possible value?

Tags: audio

We have developed a Digital Loudness Meter compliant to ITU(BS. 1770) and EBU (r128).

The problem is, for one of the streams we are getting value of Program (i.e. Integrated) Loudness as 4.53 LUFS (or LKFS).
My question is, is it possible to have positive LUFS or LKFS value for Program Loudness?

What is the maximum loudness value that can be represented with LUFS or LKFS scale (Program Loudness) like we have 0db as the Maximum value for dBFS scale.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Possible

- if your rounding error accumulates and ends up in barely noticed positive value
- if your true peak measurement gets you above zero dB
- if you have a bug - which is the most probable case with `+4.53` LU result

Comment: Roman,
Is it the value acceptable?
or there is bug in my application?

The value I have mentioned are for Integrated Loudness.

Comment: The value looks like a bug, as I mentioned. Does meter give valid output on the test vectors?